# multiline text in varchar2 field

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

I have a multiline date, and I'd like to insert it in a table. Then of course, I'd like to retrieve it while preserving the places of cartridge returns.

For example. I have data like this in text file

```
-------------------------------
| ID  |   text                |
|     |                       |
| 01  |  This is headline.    |
| 02  |  This is all the text.|
|     |  ¤                    |
|     |  Of great story once  |
| 03  |  Great weather        |
-------------------------------
```

The ¤ is the indicator of cartridge return. When I try to run the query then data comes like this:

```
-------------------------------
| ID  |   text                |
|     |                       |
| 01  |  This is headline.    |
| 02  |  This is all the text.|
| 03  |  Great weather        |
-------------------------------
```

What I'd like to have in table: (I have no idea how to show cartridge return in the example below)

```
-----------------------------------------------------
| ID  |   text                                      |
|     |                                             |
| 01  |  This is headline.                          |
| 02  |  This is all the text. Of great story once  |
| 03  |  Great weather                              |
-----------------------------------------------------
```

Which is of course, wrong as the data for ID 02 wasn't imported completely.

Here is my script:

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE "file.txt" BADFILE "file.bad" DISCARDFILE "file.dsc"
APPEND
INTO TABLE text_table
FIELDS TERMINATED BY X'7C' TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
    employee_id,           
    exp_pro CHAR(4000)
)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: how are you viewing the data?  Have you tried dumping the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First make sure the issue isn't with how you're viewing the data (or the IDE used).  Sometimes viewers will simply stop at a linefeed (or carriage return, or some binary char).

Try dumping a hex representation of some data first.  for example:

```
with txt as (
select 'This is line 1.' || chr(13) || chr(10) || 'Line 2.' as lines
from dual
)
select dump(txt.lines, 16) from txt;
```

You should be able to see the 0d0a (crlf) chars, or whatever other "non-printable" chars exists, if any.